# Problem with using worker in nativescript plugin

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-plugin

I created my first plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-ftp-client
And it is working when in development mode (using seed project), But when I package it app says it cannot find a ftp-worker-android.js file which is included
Problem is that I am using `new Worker('./ftp-worker-android.js');` and it gives an error. If I try to include it with import at the beginning of a file it get's included so
I know that it is in the package but worker can't seem to load, it gives following error:
`JS: [Error: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Failed to find module: "./ftp-worker-android.js", relative to: app//`

Comment: Does this happen on a webpack build (`--bundle`)?

Comment: Yes, I use my app in --bundle mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to conditionally use `nativescript-worker-loader` plugin to initialise worker on webpack builds.

```
    var worker;
    if (global.TNS_WEBPACK) {
        var GrayscaleWorker = require('nativescript-worker-loader!./ftp-worker-android.js');
        worker = new GrayscaleWorker();
    } else {
        worker = new Worker('./ftp-worker-android.js');
    }
```

Comment: As I am developing plugin in plain JS, is there a way to do it inside a plugin so that users using this plugin don't need to change webpack config? As I see on the plugin installation guide you need to include that plugin in webpack.config.js

Comment: This has nothing to do with webpack config. The code above is just a replacement for your require statement within plug-in